# Temporarily disable history in zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history, privacy

How can I enter some kind of "private" **zsh** shell session where none of my commands will be recorded in the on-disk history?

I know there is an option for adding a space character before any/each command to avoid it being recorded in the history, however, I'm looking for a solution that is not requiring adding a space in front of each command.

Answer (score 16):

Launch a new `zsh` shell and disable history within it.

### Option 1

```sh
zsh # or just `$SHELL` if you're already running zsh
unset HISTFILE
...secret commands...
exit
```

The secret commands won't be stored in the history file.

### Option 2

```sh
zsh # or just `$SHELL` if you're already running zsh
fc -p
...secret commands...
exit
```

The `fc -p` will switch `zsh` to a in-memory history that will be discarded when you `exit`.

The downside: the previous history (commands entered *before* the `private` session started) will not be available.